# how to make a range plot looks like a density plot in R

Tags: r, plot, density-plot

If I have a dataset looks like this

```
          gene     start       end
1 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153633399
2 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153634110
3        CRTC2 153633035 153948664
4        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
5        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
6        CRTC2 153633035 153951891
```

the start and end is the position of the gene events happened.

and I want to plot them into a density plot, where the x-axis means the position and y -axis means the frequency of gene events happened on that position, then the code I constructed was like below:

```
List <- NULL
for (i in (1:nrow(pan))){
  vec <- c(seq(pan$start[i],pan$end[i]))
  List[[i]] <- vec
}
vveec <- unlist(List)
df <- data.frame(cat=c(rep("pan",length(vveec) )), weight=vveec)
```

however, it runs slow because I first make make all the positions into rows and then plot them, for example, for gene: RP1-178F15.4 in row 1, I need to make additional rows that annotated the positions:

```
       cat      position
1 RP1-178F15.4 153633035
2 RP1-178F15.4 153633036
3 RP1-178F15.4 153633037
4 RP1-178F15.4 153633038
5 RP1-178F15.4 153633039
6 RP1-178F15.4 153633040
7 RP1-178F15.4 153633041
```

and the density plot would look like this

```
d <- density(df$weight) # returns the density data 
plot(d) # plots results
```

[image]

Because the data frame for plotting the density plot were extremely huge. Therefore, I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this?

I have tried to run them, but I need a faster way to construct the plot

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is correct, but here is a potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "          gene     start       end
1 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153633399
2 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153634110
3        CRTC2 153633035 153948664
4        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
5        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
6        CRTC2 153633035 153951891",
header = TRUE)
df
#>           gene     start       end
#> 1 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153633399
#> 2 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153634110
#> 3        CRTC2 153633035 153948664
#> 4        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
#> 5        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
#> 6        CRTC2 153633035 153951891

tmp <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-gene) %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  complete(value = first(value):max(value)) %>%
  fill(name)

head(tmp)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   gene [1]
#>   gene      value name 
#>   <chr>     <int> <chr>
#> 1 CRTC2 153633035 start
#> 2 CRTC2 153633035 start
#> 3 CRTC2 153633035 start
#> 4 CRTC2 153633035 start
#> 5 CRTC2 153633036 start
#> 6 CRTC2 153633037 start
tail(tmp)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   gene [1]
#>   gene             value name 
#>   <chr>            <int> <chr>
#> 1 RP1-178F15.4 153634105 end  
#> 2 RP1-178F15.4 153634106 end  
#> 3 RP1-178F15.4 153634107 end  
#> 4 RP1-178F15.4 153634108 end  
#> 5 RP1-178F15.4 153634109 end  
#> 6 RP1-178F15.4 153634110 end

tmp %>%
  filter(gene == "RP1-178F15.4") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

```r
d <- density(tmp$value)
plot(d)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

Benchmarking suggests the dplyr method is significantly faster on a larger example dataframe (~50X faster on 600 rows compared to your loop):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

df <- read.table(text = "          gene     start       end
1 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153633399
2 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153634110
3        CRTC2 153633035 153948664
4        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
5        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
6        CRTC2 153633035 153951891",
header = TRUE)
df
#>           gene     start       end
#> 1 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153633399
#> 2 RP1-178F15.4 153633035 153634110
#> 3        CRTC2 153633035 153948664
#> 4        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
#> 5        CRTC2 153633035 153951365
#> 6        CRTC2 153633035 153951891

dplyr_func <- function(df) {
  df_result <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-gene) %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  complete(value = first(value):max(value)) %>%
  fill(name)
}

loop_func <- function(df) {
List <- NULL
for (i in (1:nrow(df))){
  vec <- c(seq(df$start[i],df$end[i]))
  List[[i]] <- vec
}
vveec <- unlist(List)
df_result <- data.frame(cat=c(rep("df",length(vveec) )), weight=vveec)
}

df_large <- purrr::map_dfr(seq_len(100), ~df)

microbenchmark(dplyr_func(df_large),
               loop_func(df_large))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                  expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq
#>  dplyr_func(df_large)   99.39204  102.6129  105.2377  104.1975  105.7897
#>   loop_func(df_large) 4037.35384 4983.7655 5016.2306 5005.1599 5065.8195
#>        max neval cld
#>   133.4607   100  a 
#>  6110.1652   100   b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>